# Is it possible to manually buy an In-App Purchase from the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, in-app-purchase

Let's say we have an app, and there's an in app purchase that unlocks something, let's say for example a pro subscription. You can't buy it from the app itself, because the app is glitched or broken. Is it possible to manually buy this in-app purchase through the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can only do an in-app purchase through the app (that's the 'in-app' part).

If there's a glitch in the existing app you can either fix it, create a new app, or direct users to your website to make the purchase (there's a bunch of Apple rules about doing that so be sure to check your Apple Developer agreement).

Comment: How do you do it through a website?

Comment: You would need to sell the subscription thru your website.  It's not a trivial thing to do, it's take a lot of work to setup and perform.  There's many websites that provide instructions as well as pros/cons of this approach.  [Here's one](http://tallwave.com/secrets/development/in-app-purchases-what-you-need-to-know-before-developing-a-mobile-app/) to start.  It's about iOS so it's not a concrete example.